# Qualtrics | Save Pictures that are generated via JavaScript during the Survey

Tags: javascript, image, api, survey, qualtrics

for a survey on qualtrics I am searching for a way to save (multiple) images that are generated from the participants during the survey.

The images are user taken "screenshots" of a video presented to the participants during the survey that are caused by button presses during the presentation.

I already wrote the JavaSrcipt and HTML to show the video and generate the frames as images but I am looking for a way to somehow save those images in Qualtrics. 
I would really appreciate your help, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

The only way to save files to Qualtrics would be to utilize the file upload question type. I imagine that will get you on the right track.

Comment: Thank you very much!
Do you know any way to set the input data of the file upload question type since I found nothing documented in the API and on the web.

Comment: Since my research didn't list any results. I tried to export the Images as embedded Values encoded as BASE64 Values. When I initialize embedded Value variables at the begin of the control flow, I can easily assign them with Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.setEmbeddedData. 
Are there any constraints on the function addEmbeddedData, since any keys and values I try to add with this function are not shown in the data of the survey.